# Google drive API V3 how to correctly escape query param?

Tags: go, encoding, google-drive-api

Given: working access to Google Drive with some Folders with Space in Name

Problem: The query:

```
name='07 Dirname' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '0B22uLx7BCvv9T0FWRmNaREY4VEE' in parents and trashed=false
```

does not work over the API, but does if the dir is without space in it.
The query does work however if you run it from the [API-Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list) which provides as hint: *This parameter was URL encoded*.

However when I encode the name field with **url.QueryEscape** or **url.PathEscape** the folder can not be found. As far as I understand it its not necessary to encode the whole query, just the param, but how?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to be double encoded to work, so call url.QueryEscape first on the search given above and then again on the query string.

If you look at the API Explorer with Chrome devtools, you will see the double encoded values despite the misleading display on the page itself.

e.g. something like `https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%3D%2707+Dirname%27+and+mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27+and+%270B22uLx7BCvv9T0FWRmNaREY4VEE%27+in+parents+and+trashed%3Dfalse&key={APIKEY}`

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the access to this directory was not working. It was the default scope which is:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file    Per-file access to files
>   created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a
>   per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.

But to have access also to folders not created by the app, I need this one:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive Full, permissive scope to access
>   all of a user's files, excluding the Application Data folder. Request
>   this scope only when it is strictly necessary.

Which can be requested by setting the scope of the config like so:

```
func establishConnection() (*drive.Service, error) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("client_secret.json")
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved client_secret.json.
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, drive.DriveScope)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }

    return drive.New(getClient(config))
}
```